# Need help updating time element with output from jq?

Tags: json, jq, jtc

Current object with proposed format

```
[
  {
    "time": "2022-01-28T17:50:31.620Z"
  }
]
```

Command executed to convert from iso8601 to unix

jq '.[].time | sub("\.[0-9]+Z$"; "Z") | fromdate' time_test.json

Output
1643392231

I've tried varying combinations but how to do I update the time value in the object. I can get the conversion to work but can't seem to update the value with the output.

Expected Result -

```
[
  {
    "time": "1643392231"
  }
]
```

Comment: ```jq 'map({time_unix: (.[].time |= sub("\\.[0-9]+Z$"; "Z") | fromdate)```  I attempted to use map to create a new field and use the query above to add the output but haven't found the right combination yet.

Comment: Simple JavaScript `Math.floor(Date.parse('2022-01-28T17:50:31.620Z')/1000)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cancel the fractional seconds and you're good to go with `fromdate`. To escape within the regex, use double backslashes.

```sh
jq 'map(.time |= (sub("\\.\\d+"; "") | fromdate))'
```

```json
[
  {
    "time": 1643392231
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1DV-wFaIQt)

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You mapped all the values in the array but you're not actually modifying or recreating the array.

To modify, use an assignment: (you were almost there)

```
.[].time |= (sub("\\.\\d+Z$"; "Z") | fromdate)
```

To recreate, map it.

```
map(.time |= (sub("\\.\\d+Z$"; "Z") | fromdate))
```